# How to fix Ora-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

i getting error on:single-row subquery returns more than one row 
but yetserday i can update by code:

```
begin

for x in (select rowid as ib_rowid,T_T_INBOX.* from T_T_INBOX where MESSAGE_TYPE = 'LCSR') 
loop
  update T_T_INBOX 
  set T_T_INBOX.DOC_EXCHANGE_ID = (select doc.Id as Doc_Ex_id 
                                  from T_T_DOC_EXCHANGE doc 
                                  inner join T_T_INBOX ib on ib.KEY_FIELD1 = doc.REFERENCE_ID
                                  inner join T_T_LICENSE_REJECT lire on ib.id = lire.MESSAGE_IN_ID
                                  where ib.MESSAGE_TYPE = 'LCSR'
                                  and ib.rowid = x.ib_rowid)



  where rowid = x.ib_rowid;

end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Just run the inner select by replacing `ib.rowid = <ROWID>` . It should be returning more than one rows now after your yesterday's update. Since you have joins , there can be `> 1` rows from other tables

Answer (score 0):

Your inner select statement

```
select doc.Id as Doc_Ex_id 
                                  from T_T_DOC_EXCHANGE doc 
                                  inner join T_T_INBOX ib on ib.KEY_FIELD1 = doc.REFERENCE_ID
                                  inner join T_T_LICENSE_REJECT lire on ib.id = lire.MESSAGE_IN_ID
                                  where ib.MESSAGE_TYPE = 'LCSR'
                                  and ib.rowid = x.ib_rowid
```

is returning more than one row (Possible cartesian product because of a missing join condition? Possible presence of two rows with same IDs?). You have to make sure that for every row in T_T_INBOX, the subquery returns exactly one row as the update statement cannot update a column to two different value. Hence the error.

Alternatively, you can use the oracle [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement.
It appears that you want to update the DOC_EXCHANGE_ID column in T_T_INBOX table by finding out the ID from the T_T_DOC_EXCHANGE table using some join condition on the T_T_LICENSE_REJECT table (I didn't understand this). But anyway, MERGE is designed exactly to do this without having to resort to PLSQL.

Maybe you want to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal way to solve this problem is to use an in instead of = But since here you are trying to update some rows,oracle will expect a single output from the inner query and it might throw some error in the update if you use an in there .I would suggest do it in a loop using a cursor fetch values which you need to update and then do it one by one